# How to undo git rm

Tags: git

I have accidentally added and committed a (huge) log file into my local git repository and then did a `git rm` (without --cached). So the history looks like this:

```
> git status

modified:  Foo.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    huge_file.log

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Then I did `git add .`:

```
> git add .
> git status

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:  Foo.java
    new file:   huge_file.log
```

Then (I have overlooked that I've added `huge_file.log`) I did a `git commit`:

```
> git commit -am "Foo commit"
[master 7582793] Foo commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 huge_file.log
```

Then I realized that I have added and committed  `huge_file.log`. So I thought I could undo that by doing `git rm huge_file.log`:

```
> git rm huge_file.log
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    huge_file.log
```

So at this point, I realized the mess I made: I can't commit and push to master this changes because that would mean pushing `huge_file.log` and then deleting `huge_file.log`. Unfortunately, I can't push since we have a file limit of 100 MB per file and `huge_file.log` is more than 1 GB.

So what can I do now? I can't simply reset HEAD to a previous commit since I have made a lot of changes in `Foo.java` that I don't want to undo.

Is there a way to change the previous commit to remove `huge_file.log` somehow.

Please note that `Foo.java` is just representative for better readability here on StackOverflow. I have touched about 10 files and modified many lines of code in each file, and I don't want to lose this changes.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's just in the last commit, 
then do `git rm huge_file.log` and then `git commit --amend`.

Git allows you to make *amend*s for the last error you've *commit*ted. Literally.

Comment: This doesn't undo the `git rm` as requested in the question's title

Answer (score 6):

If you have not committed yet. You can use `git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree <file>`

Comment: On ruuning this command, I got this error `git: 'restore' is not a git command.`

Comment: @Mohit Update git to at least 2.23.0

Comment: `git restore --staged <file>` then `git checkout <file>` is what I had to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~[n]
```

where `[n]` is the number of commits in the past you wish to reset.

For example, to undo your last commit

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1
$ git status
```

And then proceed to commit files as you would normally do.